# How to take 9:41 am screenshots on an iOS Simulator and Device?

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode, development, xcode-simulator

I know that it's possible to record the screen on Yosemite and take screenshots that have 9:41 am.  Is this same functionality possible with the Simulator?

Answer (score 24):

Starting with Xcode 11 beta 4, you can use the `xcrun simctl` command to set the time and battery in the Simulator.

```
xcrun simctl status_bar <device> override --time "9:41" \
    --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100
```

Example of usage:

```
xcrun simctl status_bar "iPhone 11 Pro Max" override --time "9:41" \
    --batteryState charged --batteryLevel 100
```

The simulator needs to be run before executing the command.

See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_beta_4_release_notes for more details.

There is a tool to loop across all running simulators and also handle time zones a bit better than explicitly calling it each time: `2020-09-15T09:41:00-07:00`

- https://github.com/jessesquires/Nine41

Comment: Thanks, my iOS Simulator gives me low battery anxiety when it shows the red warning icon. This saved my day!

Comment: Use `booted` instead of `<device>` to apply the settings to all running simulators.

Comment: You can also set the date (which is displayed on iPads) by passing a time string with *full* ISO date format, e.g.: `"2021-06-28T07:32:00-07:00"`

Comment: @RobinStewart Or go with `2020-09-15T09:41:00-07:00` if you want to match Apple's current iPad product images. It seems like they just take the first Tuesday in the last September that has a two-digit day ordinal.

Comment: There's [Nine41](https://github.com/jessesquires/Nine41) that helps to avoid a lot of typing.

Comment: I believe the date should be 2007-01-09, the launch date of the iPhone. l went through a lot of apps, most don't follow that date. The Message app did.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. Do I just type this in the terminal app?

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 ways to do this:

### 1. Clone, build and run [SimulatorStatusMagic](https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic) in your simulator.

> This will only work for your simulator.

https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic

```bsh
cd ~/Desktop
git clone git@github.com:shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic.git
cd ~/Desktop/SimulatorStatusMagic
open SimulatorStatusMagic.xcodeproj/
# Build the "Framework" Target
# Build & RUN the "SimulatorStatusMagic" in your Emulator
```

### 2. via QuickTime Player:

> This will only work for your device.

- Connect your own device to your Mac.
- Open "QuickTime Player" (Install if required)
- File → New **Movie** Recording
- Click the dropdown next to the Red Record button
- Select your iPhone e.g: "Anil's iPhone"
- Record and bring your screen up, then Stop the recording.
- Now you can "Play" your recording, find the screen you want, pause it,
  Edit Menu → Copy (will copy the screen grab).

---

Both should result in something like this (Time 9:41 AM - Full Battery and Wifi):

[image: How to take a 9 41 AM iPhone Screenshot]

Comment: This tool is useful if you have iOS 12 or lower and/or Xcode 10 or lower.

Comment: Thank you, it works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

I simply run this command in the terminal after running my code on the simulator:

`xcrun simctl status_bar booted override --time "2007-01-09T09:41:00-6:00" --wifiBars 3 --cellularBars 4 --batteryLevel 100`

You will need to replace the timezone `-6:00` to whatever yours is.

Comment: How does that command differ from the one in the question - ie what exact part of the command line does the OP need to chnage? and preferably explain why

Answer (score -1):

Now that Apple has delivered a tool to manage this, use [Nine41](https://github.com/jessesquires/Nine41) and/or `xcrun simctl status_bar`

Those are far more time efficient than fixing it in post production with Photoshop or Pixelmator or Acorn and your video editor of choice as you are in [to pay attention to these details](https://xkcd.com/1373/).

One screen shot at the right time with light and dark backgrounds let you adjust the battery level, bars, time and more to suit your needs.

There are even plug in to the simulator that will programmatically clean up the status bar for more than just time if you are running your code that way and not on a device:

- https://github.com/shinydevelopment/SimulatorStatusMagic