# Time setting on iPad changes when I cable-connect to laptop (during Zoom)

Tags: ios, ipad

I teach on Zoom with my iPad Air connected to my MacBook Pro laptop by cable. I experience the following problem/bug that I would like to have fixed:

1. My MacBook Pro laptop has the correct time.
2. My iPad Air (3rd gen) has the correct time.
3. When I connect my iPad to my laptop via a cable, **my iPad suddenly changes to a random and incorrect time.** This instantly fixes itself when I disconnect the cable.

In particular, the instant I "share screen" in Zoom (meaning the Zoom session that I am running on my laptop shares the screen of the Ipad via a cable connection), **my iPad suddenly displays an incorrect time that has nothing to do with either the time setting of my laptop or the original time setting of my iPad**. This is frustrating because I need to view the time while I am teaching, but I consistently view the *incorrect time* when I look at my iPad screen (I have to remember to view my laptop screen for the correct time).

Comment: In the Zoom client on macOS, go to Preferences > General and click the View More Settings weblink at the bottom of the window. Login to your Zoom account on the webpage that opens, then select Profile. Check to make sure that Time Zone under the Date and Time section is correct.

Comment: @IconDaemon : That does not seem to work (although I was able to change something else on Zoom by finding the "profile" page you mentioned).  I am in Los Angeles and I set Zoom to "Pacific Time US and Canada" and when I plug my iPad  into my laptop at 10:23 PT, the iPad incorrectly displays 9:41am.  It goes back to the correct time when I unplug my cable.

Comment: Ten minutes later my iPad still says 9:41am when plugged into my laptop on Zoom share-screen.  I think it is frozen at 9:41am.

Comment: Is the _iPad_ set to the correct time zone, too? Have you [force-restarted](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-reset-an-ipad/) the iPad? I also suggest you try connecting with another cable, preferably a new one. Having worked with hundreds of iPads, a few bad cables (which cannot be identified by sight alone) have caused headaches. We have many teachers where I work who connect iPads to their MacBooks, and this particular problem has never come up.

Comment: I have _exactly_ this same problem, even down to the 9:41am.  It's very frustrating when I teach and record my screen.  I have _no idea_ what's going on and would love to learn the fix.  4th G iPad Pro up to date; mid-2012 MacBook Pro as up to date as it can be; up to date Zoom.

Comment: Same issue here. Interestingly, 9:41 is always the time used on all screenshots of iphones and ipads.

Comment: @anonymous only when plugged in to a Mac. Screenshots should show the correct time when unplugged. But the reason why the time is showing as 9:41am 9 Jan is because that is the time Steve Jobs released the first iPhone publicly in 2007

Answer (score 1):

Was this figured out? As others have said, I have the same issue with the same time 9:41. It makes me concerned when I teach because I see the time and think I have gone over until I remember the issue.  (apologies for not commenting instead. I just joined and it won't let me).

Comment: I bet you have the answer! https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/154511/how-to-take-941-am-screenshots-on-an-ios-simulator-and-device XCode likely has a setting to change the time so all screen shots are 9:41 for [historical reasons](https://www.engadget.com/2014-04-14-why-9-41-am-is-the-always-the-time-displayed-on-iphones-and-ipad.html).

Comment: @Andrea Welsh: No, this was never figured out. At least, I do not know how to fix it.  My 9:41am problem persists.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/311421)

Answer (score 1):

I still see this issue whenever the iPad screen is shared via cable. The date and time becomes fixed for the duration of the share, as 09:41 Tue 9 Jan.
Stopping screen sharing from the iPad will return the correct time.

This is only via cable; sharing via Airplay does not cause this anomaly.

Comment: Yes, this is the time that Steve Jobs publicly released the iPhone on January 9th 2007. For a detailed explainer see: https://www.engadget.com/2014-04-14-why-9-41-am-is-the-always-the-time-displayed-on-iphones-and-ipad.html

Comment: @AVelj So is this a bug or intentional? I can understand displaying 9:41 AM in ads as a cute homage to iPhone, but that's quite different from having it display as the time when screen-sharing during a meeting!

Comment: @WillG It's intentional

Comment: @AVelj This seems like a very weird decision to me. Don't people ever actually look at the clock when someone is sharing their screen? Unlike in an ad, where no one would ever expect the date and time to be accurate, this is a needless source of confusion for real-time screen sharing in meetings.